# getting/embedding user id in url/templates

Tags: django

i am fairly new to django and i want to update some of my contents in the django DB 
for this i have written a little view function. which looks like this

```
def status_change(request,id):
    instance = get_object_or_404(register,id=id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
       rform = registerForm(instance=instance, data=request.POST)
       if rform.is_valid():
          instance = rform.save()
          return render_to_response('home.html')
    else:
        rform = registerForm(instance=instance)
        return render_to_response('status_change.html',{'rform':rform})
```

i want to pass this "id" from template to the "view". 
my urls lopk like this

```
      (r'^status/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.status_change),
```

and when i use

```
      (r'^status/(?P<id>\d+)$', views.status_change, name ='status_change'),
```

it barks as  syntax error on this line
and in my template i have

```
<a href = "/status/{{user.id}}">Change Status</a>
```

but this whole thing is not getting the id from the template/url
am i making a mistake somewhere. any help will be greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for every one 
i got a simple way but i dont know is it a good practice or not
instead of getting the user id from the template/urls 
i simpley put this thing in my code and it works fine

```
def status_change(request):
    instance = get_object_or_404(register,pk=request.user.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You given it nothing to get `user` from. Pass it a `RequestContext`.

And use `{% url %}`.

The syntax error comes from the fact that tuples cannot have named arguments. Perhaps you wanted `url()` instead.

Comment: any snippet or example please

Answer (score 1):

If you need the id of the current user, you can also user django's request context processor http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django-core-context-processors-request, which enables you to access it through `{{ request.user.id }}`.

Comment: I strongly second the idea of using context processors for making "standard values" available across all of your views/templates. It really reduces the amount of redundant value passing. Checkout RequestContext - http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#id1